# KnockoutJS - Custom Bindings with arguments

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to write custom knockout bindings to some JavaScript "rendering" functions, so that I could do stuff like:

```
<td data-bind="numeral('0%'): interest">
```

Behind the scenes, this hypothetical numeral would be doing something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numeral(fmt) = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContent) {
    var unwrapped = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    $(element).html(numeral(unwrapped).format(fmt));
  }
}
```

I gave this definition a go, and JavaScript really didn't like me trying to abstract on the numeral key.  How should I approach the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try like this.

```
<td data-bind="numeral: interest, fmt : '0%'">
```

And the binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numeral = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContent) {
    var unwrapped = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    var fmtVal = allBindings.get('fmt') || '0%'; 
    $(element).html(numeral(unwrapped).format(fmtVal));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using multiple bindings as named parameters is pretty slick.

Comment: While this solution works, I believe that it is misleading to leverage the allBindings.get() getter to retrieve the value for an argument meant for another custom binding. This essentially implies that you have a binding that is called fmt, which may not necessarily be the case. Take a look below for an alternate solution.

Comment: This is how it worked for me var dateFormat =allBindingsAccessor().fmt || 'MM/DD/YYYY';

I was getting an error on the allBindings.get('fmt') .get method

Answer (score 32):

Answers provided here are nice tricks, but knockout actually has a way of doing this.

```
<td data-bind="numeral: {interest: interest, fmt: '0%' }">
```

and in your custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numeral(fmt) = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContent) {
    var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    // unwrapped.interest... = interest
    // unwrapped.fmt... = fmt ('0%' in this case)

  }
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: This actually is the best answer for the question.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer even if it was two years after the fact. This is nice functionality and perfectly fits my needs.

Comment: Great answer, I would just add that you might want to unwrap each binding as well. This way you can bind it to an observable or an expression.  
Ex. `var interset = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(unwrapped.interest)`

Answer (score 5):

An alternate option is to add a custom data attribute to the element that required the extra argument for the binding:

```
<td data-bind="numeral: interest" data-format="0%">
```

And then inside of the binding you can extract the value of the attribute from the element target.

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.numeral = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContent) {
           // ... some more code
            var fmtVal = $(element).data("format") || '0%'; 
           // ... do stuff with fmtVal 
    }}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could pass as the parameter for your custom binding an object. Something like:

```
<td data-bind="numeral: numeralOptions">
```

In your viewmodel the correspondant object:

```
numeralOptions = {
    interest: ko.observable(808),
    format: '0%'
}
```

Then in the custom binding, using valueAccessor you can access to whatever initial parameter you need for your duty.

```
var myObject = valueAccessor();
myObject.interest();
myObject.format;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of making a function or computed observable called interest and if its a function it can take a parameter. It would then be of the form:
        data-bind="numeral: interest('0%')"
From this you could then write the binding handler to do render js for your purpose.